# MySql 3 tables join, group and sum

Tags: mysql

I want to add order totals together and then group them by site owner
I have 3 tables

```
orders
subtotal | site

site_data
site_owner | record_id

site
record_id
```

the relationship between these are
sites.site_data = site_data.record_id
sites.record_id = orders.site

currently this is what I have

```
SELECT site_data.site_owner,
SUM('orders.subtotal')
FROM site_data
INNER JOIN site ON site.site_data = site_data.record_id
INNER JOIN orders ON site.record_id = orders.site
group by site_data.site_owner
```

but the output is as follows

```
site_owner | SUM('orders,subtotal')
Mr Foo     | 0
Mr Bar     | 0
```

all the orders totals are 0 and I am not sure why I have done a sum on this field before and not had an issue so must be to do with the grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use quotes inside SUM function

> SELECT site_data.site_owner,
>   **SUM(orders.subtotal)**
>   FROM site_data
>   INNER JOIN site ON site.site_data = site_data.record_id
>   INNER JOIN orders ON site.record_id = orders.site
>   group by site_data.site_owner